# Can we have a "digital-signage" tag for Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

There are many questions pertaining to digital signage applications but they are difficult to search for because they cannot be properly tagged.

Comment: Could you point to some examples so people can examine the merits of the suggestion on their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply create a Tag. You have to do so while asking a question about it and having the right amount of repuatation to create tags. Make you must have questions about the this in your head before considering adding a tag bout it.

You should also note that (from the [create tag page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags)):

> - new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

Comment: +1 just because "I'm keeping it's reputation low so I can test new users restrictions when I'm bug hunting."

Comment: -1 just because "I'm keeping it's reputation low so I can test new users restrictions when I'm bug hunting." Every upvote moves the poor sock puppet away from its core mission!

Comment: @Pekka  true haha I just coudnt resist answering this